# Plot mean and std. dev. at specific hourly ticks using Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame in the following format:

```
                       Ozone  CellT  CellP  FlowRate
Date/Time
10/06/14 15:49:57   40.4   32.6  978.6      2297
10/06/14 15:54:57   44.0   32.7  978.6      2267
10/06/14 15:59:57   44.7   32.8  978.6      2249
10/06/14 16:04:57   45.0   32.9  978.6      2262
10/06/14 16:09:57   45.0   32.9  978.6      2286
```

I want to plot it as the hourly average of the ozone reading versus the timestamp, with an overlay of  plus/minus the standard deviation.

When I currently the current ozone reading, the x-axis (timestamp) has an arbitrary time stamp on it such as "10/06/14 15:49:57". I'd like to have each x-axis tick mark at different days on 12:00:00.

How do I proceed with plotting the average value from the last hour, versus the timestamp with ticks at 12:00:00 daily?

EDIT:
The following works for calculating the mean and std on an hourly basis. What I want to do now is pad the values and plot them with correct tick marks.

```
df['OzoneHourlyMean'] = df.Ozone.resample('H', how='mean')
df['OzoneHourlyStd'] = df.Ozone.resample('H', how='std')
```

The commands above produces data in the following format:

```
2014-06-10 15:00:00    43.033333
2014-06-10 16:00:00    44.291667
2014-06-10 17:00:00    44.691667
2014-06-10 18:00:00    45.175000
2014-06-10 19:00:00    44.433333
```

Comment: What do you mean by "overlay of the standard deviation"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean to display the mean +/- std.

Comment: Do you wish to display the standard deviation as vertical error bars?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In response to this, which I think is what's left in the edited question

> How do I proceed with plotting the average value from the last hour, versus the timestamp with ticks at 12:00:00 daily?

I think all you want to do is set the tick marks on noon every day.  You can generate your own list of ticks and then use those.  The interaction with pandas might mess up xticks, so I'd probably just use straight up matplotlib.  For you, something like this?

```
tickv = pd.date_range('10/06/2014 12:00:00', periods=5, freq = 'D')
plt.plot(df.index, df['OzoneHourlyMean'])
plt.xticks(tickv)
```