# Python: Calculating Average and Standard deviation for every hour in csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large csv files, and the data looks like this:

```
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS    |     Temperature   |      Magnetic
2015-12-07 20:51:06:608  |        22.7       |        32.3
2015-12-07 20:51:07:609  |        22.5       |        47.7
  ....                            ...                  ...
```

Now I want to use python with pandas to create a csv that looks like this:

```
   Hour       |     Average Temp   |    Average Mag
   20:00      |         22.6       |       40
   21:00      |         ...        |       ...
```

and so on for each of the 24 hours.

the second thing is I want to do the same average, but for every day of the month:

```
Date       |     Average Temp   |    Average Mag
7-12-2015  |         22.6       |       40
8-12-2015  |         ...        |       ...
```

Is there a good way to do it in python ?
I've tried excel, but the csv's are very very large and I have bunch of them (hopefully to create a loop for doing the same thing to every file)

Thank you !

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247156/plot-mean-and-std-dev-at-specific-hourly-ticks-using-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html),
then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last 
[`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with aggregating 
[`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and  [`std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html)

In version `0.18.0` in new [resample api](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#resample-api)

```
#convert column to datetime
df['YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

#set index from column
df = df.set_index('YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

#resample and aggregate mean
print df.resample('H').mean()
                       Temperature  Magnetic
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS                       
2015-12-07 20:00:00           22.6      40.0

print df.resample('H').std()
                       Temperature   Magnetic
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS                        
2015-12-07 20:00:00       0.141421  10.889444

print df.resample('D').mean()
                       Temperature  Magnetic
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS                       
2015-12-07                    22.6      40.0
print df.resample('D').std()
                       Temperature   Magnetic
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS                        
2015-12-07                0.141421  10.889444
```

If you want aggregate all to new columns , you can use:

```
#resample and aggregate mean
df1 = df.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
df1.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
print df1.reset_index()
  YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS  Temperature mean  Temperature std  Magnetic mean  \
0   2015-12-07 20:00:00              22.6         0.141421           40.0   

   Magnetic std  
0     10.889444  

df2 = df.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
df2.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df2.columns]
print df2.reset_index()
  YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS  Temperature mean  Temperature std  Magnetic mean  \
0            2015-12-07              22.6         0.141421           40.0   

   Magnetic std  
0     10.889444
```

If you need write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (maybe without index):

```
df1.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thank you very much !!! just one thing, instead of just printing the results - how can i write them directly to a new csv ? thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Average Temp'] = df.Temperature.resample('H', how='mean')
```